# Regex only letters except set of numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using `Replace(@"[^a-zA-Z]+", "");`
leave only letters, but I have a set of numbers or characters that I want to keep as well, ex: 122456 and 112466. But I'm having trouble leaving it only if it's this sequence:

ex input:

```
abc 1239 asm122456000
```

I want to:

```
abscasm122456
```

tried this: `([^a-zA-Z])+|(?!122456)`

Comment: Are you looking for the specific string "122456" or "112466", or any 6 digit sequence of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

*My answer doesn't applying `Replace()`, but achieves a similar result:*

```
(?:[a-zA-Z]+|\d{6})
```

which captures the group (non-capturing group) with the alphabetic character(s) or a set of digits with 6 occurrences.

[Regex 101 & Test Result](https://regex101.com/r/9TsLpt/1)

---

Join all the matching values into a single string.

```cs
using System.Linq;

Regex regex = new Regex("(?:[a-zA-Z]+|\\d{6})");
string input = "abc 1239 asm12245600";
string output = "";

var matches = regex.Matches(input);
if (matches.Count > 0)          
    output = String.Join("", matches.Select(x => x.Value));
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/boHbk7)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way,

using `.Split()` and `.All()`,

```
string input = "abc 1239 asm122456000";
string output = string.Join("", input.Split().Where(x => !x.All(char.IsDigit)));
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IXP367)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple: you need to *match and capture* what you need to keep, and just match what you need to remove, and then utilize a backreference to the captured group value in the replacement pattern to put it back into the resulting string.

Here is the regex:

```
(122456|112466)|[^a-zA-Z]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1QhcUY/2). *Details*:

- `(122456|112466)` - Capturing group with ID 1: either of the two alternatives
- `|` - or
- `[^a-zA-Z]` - a char other than an ASCII letter (use `\P{L}` if you need to match any char other than any Unicode letter).

**Note** the removed `+` quantifier as `[^A-Za-z]` also matches digits.

You need to use `$1` in the replacement:

```cs
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"(122456|112466)|[^a-zA-Z]", "$1");
```